# Constructing HTML after getJSON works in Safari but not in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i'm actually a newbie using javascript and html/css.

I can't understand why my script works on safari, but not on chrome and firefox...
any ideas?

EDIT: Both in chrome anda firefox the ul and li elements do not show... Also the previous alerts don't work. I'll check errors in the console and edit the post again

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="patients" style="text-align:center">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON("http://www.url.com/json",
                      function(data) {

                      var items = [];
                      alert(data[1].patient);
                      alert(data[1].hr);

                      $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                             items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' + val.patient + '<div style="display: none" id="'+val.patient+'"></div></li>');
                             });

                      $('<ul/>', {
                        'class': 'my-new-list',
                        html: items.join('')
                        }).appendTo('#patients');


                      });
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define 'not working'. What have you tried? What errors are you getting? What alerts are and aren't shown?

Comment: Me neither. Can you update your post, and elaborate the "question"? What's not working (what did you expect, what does not happen). Also, choose a more descriptive title..

Comment: @RobW: You have enough reputation to help out this newbie. By the content of this question you could easily edit question title. Providing help to new users is more proactive than categorically voting them down and complaining... Offer help and guidance.

Comment: @user848778: You have to make sure that we understand the problem. One suggestion you can do: check your data using Firebug in FF and see if your script works without errors. Just by looking at your code it surely seems it should work. You could also provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that proves your issue and we can run it and see for ourselves and try to help you out by example.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'class'`. Object property names shouldn't quoted.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you have to understand is when javascript executes on the page.

So in the code you have posted, the browser first loads the jquery library. When it encounters your `<script>` tag, it then attempts to execute the `$.getJSON()` function.

In your script, on the successful completion of the json request, its attempting to modify the DOM by adding generated html to `#patients`. This won't work 100% of the time because you can't guarantee the browser has rendered #patients yet.

You should start by wrapping your javascript code inside a wrapper that only executes after page load.

This can be done in a few ways. These are the jQuery specific methods here, since that's what you're using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code
});
```

Or:

```
$(function(){
    //your code
});
```

The native javascript code would look something like:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(){
    //your code
}, false);
```

I would recommend using one of the jQuery methods.

As an added tip, you don't need to put `type="text/javascript"` in your script tag. All browsers understand that a script tag means javascript. Luckily we are well past the old days of various broken versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @user848778: I object the non-type usage. I suggest you **always** use mime type of your script tag content, because it's arguably more *conventional*. But I do agree with everything else Geuis said (+1 for that). Use the second one that runs your script on DOM ready and not immediately.

Comment: Tried your solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm using chrome and firefox on Os X mountain lion. Safari works well

Comment: It wasn't really a recommendation, it was a mandatory first step. You *have* to delay script execution until after DOM ready. Now after that, we can start troubleshooting your problem if you post more data.